# PHP strpos differentiating between two similar words

Tags: php, substr, strpos

I'm trying to parse a file, but I'm hampered by the fact that I'm trying to find the `strpos` of a word which is similar to another word in the file.
For instance, my files has something like

```
BEGIN_DATA_567 329
...
END_DATA_567

BEGIN_DATA 561
....
END_DATA
```

(the 329 and 561 after the markers are just dummy data)

I'm trying to match on the `BEGIN_DATA` and `END_DATA`, not `BEGIN_DATA_567` and `END_DATA_567` but of course it picks up on the first occurrence, which is wrong. 
I'm trying to use

```
$word1='BEGIN_DATA';
$word2='END_DATA';
```

And then getting the data between them using

```
$between=substr($contents, strpos($contents, $word1), strpos($contents, $word2) - strpos($contents, $word1));
```

Of course this doesn't work - it picks up on `BEGIN_DATA_567`. I've tried doing things like

```
$word1="BEGIN_DATA "; and $word1="BEGIN_DATA\t";
```

because the `strpos` I am trying to get has a space after it but of course "`BEGIN_DATA_567`" doesn't but nothing seems to work.

Comment: "\t" is a tab character, not a space

Comment: I know but I was desperate enough to try anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preg_match](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-match.php). Here's a working solution:

```
preg_match('/BEGIN_DATA /', $contents, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$start  = $matches[0][1];

preg_match('/END_DATA$/', $contents, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$end  = $matches[0][1];

$between=substr($contents, $start, $end - $start);
```

Comment: I can strip off the BEGIN_DATA 561 using regex, the head scratcher was trying to get the code to differentiate between the two similar BEGIN_DATA blocks.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the contents between BEGIN_DATA and END_DATA, using *preg_match()*:

```
preg_match("/\bBEGIN_DATA\b(.+)\bEND_DATA\b/s", $str, $match);

echo $match[1];
```

[**See demo**](http://3v4l.org/o2Rs1)

Using *strpos()*, your attempt to use `$word1 = 'BEGIN_DATA ';` is a good thought, but it fails because of the `$word2`. If `END_DATA` always had a space after it, this would work (you need to account for the length of `$word1`):

```
$word1 = 'BEGIN_DATA ';
$word2 = 'END_DATA ';

$between = substr(
    $contents, 
    strpos($contents, $word1) + strlen($word1), 
    strpos($contents, $word2) - (strpos($contents, $word1) + strlen($word1))
);
```

There are some other options that could work, but you need to know the "rules" of `$contents`. For instance, is `END_DATA` always at the very end? Does `%BEGIN_DATA%*` or `%END_DATA%` appear anywhere between the actual starting and ending points? Given enough knowledge about the expected input, you could make your *strpos()* method work - but I would just use *preg_match()*

Comment: Thanks for your comment; the structure of the data file is well described, and the DATA_567 block occurs before the DATA block, and that is usually the last thing in the file, but occasionally diagnostics are performed which puts a big chunk of extra data afterwards, so the trick looking right at the very end of the file would only work sometimes.